# socket.io - Events don't fire properly

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a simple web app and this is my client side script

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on("debug",(msg)=>console.log(msg));
socket.on("pong",()=>console.log("PONG"));
```

Server side code :

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var socket = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../UI")));

socket.on("connection",(s)=>{
    s.on("ping",()=>{
        console.log("New ping req");
        s.emit("pong");
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Now here's what's bothering me for the past one hour. If i go to my chrome console and type in `socket.emit("ping");` I don't get a response immediately, it prints out "PONG" every 20 seconds or so and on the server nothing is printed even though I put the console.log inside my ping event. I made sure to check the file was saved to disk, checked the source in chrome and even rebooted and switched to firefox and it's the same. I have worked with socket.io many time in the past and I have no clue to why this is happening now. Totally lost. Btw I'm running Arch Linux and compiled node.js v10.1.0 from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling with the code for hours and contemplating everything, I finally found that "ping" and "pong" are reserved events. It's listed in the documentation of socket.io in the emit cheat sheet section.